# Spring Exception on starting Application

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, nhibernate-mapping

I had taken reference from [Vannilla](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html) for Spring Hibernate Integration Example.

When I start Tomcat with the Application, following error occurs:

```
27 Dec, 2011 6:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I had edit the User class and DB parameters according to my requirement.

Here is my User Class:

```
package com.vaannila.domain;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USERREGISTRATION_NEW")
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String sex;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private String courses;
    private String exams;
    private String newsletter;
    private String createdDate;
    private int country_id;
    private int state_id;
    private int city_id;
    private String addressIP;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    @Column(name="SEX")
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    @Column(name="PHONE")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="DOB")
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    @Column(name="COURSES")
    public String getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
    public void setCourses(String courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    @Column(name="EXAMS")
    public String getExams() {
        return exams;
    }
    public void setExams(String exams) {
        this.exams = exams;
    }
    @Column(name="NEWSLETTER")
    public String getNewsletter() {
        return newsletter;
    }
    public void setNewsletter(String newsletter) {
        this.newsletter = newsletter;
    }
    @Column(name="CREATEDDATE")
    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    @Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
    public int getCountry_id() {
        return country_id;
    }
    public void setCountry_id(int country_id) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
    }
    @Column(name="STATE_ID")
    public int getState_id() {
        return state_id;
    }
    public void setState_id(int state_id) {
        this.state_id = state_id;
    }

    @Column(name="CITY_ID")
    public int getCity_id() {
        return city_id;
    }
    public void setCity_id(int city_id) {
        this.city_id = city_id;
    }

    @Column(name="ADDRESSIP")
    public String getAddressIP() {
        return addressIP;
    }
    public void setAddressIP(String addressIP) {
        this.addressIP = addressIP;
    }   

}
```

**I had created all setters & getters for every variable.**

**Then still exception shows error in setID**

**I cannot understand why this problem occurs?**

Comment: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext is not a User class or am I missing something? what is your bean configuration?

Comment: dispatcher-servlet.xml:-> <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />  <bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAOImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
 </bean>
 
 <bean name="/user/*.htm" class="com.vaannila.web.UserController" >
  <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
 </bean> and 2 more beans for SessionFactory and DataSource

Comment: Since, vannilla.com doesn't provide lib for this example. I had find lib using find.jar or www.java2s.com sites. If this approach not correct, provide the resource for locating all jars required for this example.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419745/grails-1-2-1-with-spring-3-0-0-dependency-problem-under-jetty and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450364/jersey-1-6-with-spring-3-0-5-using-maven?

Comment: Consider using maving for managing your libraries and their dependencies; it will save you hours of working stuff like this out.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with your User class but I suspect there is a problem in your classpath. Check if all spring jars are of the same version.